# Catch all exceptions from network issues

Tags: exception, connection, jsoup

I  Have a program that tries to connect to a html page via JSoup. I have this section of code inside a while loop with the aim of filling a map with at least *n* elements. In almost-pseudo-code it looks like so:

```
while(!myMap.hasFiveKeys){
    doc =JSoup.parse("http://www.website.com");
      wordMap.fillFrom(doc);
 }
```

I want this inside a catch block that would, when *any* network related exception is thrown I'd like to increment a counter, then my while condition could contain `connectionAttempts<10` so that if the connection fails 10 times it stops trying (if at first you don't succeed, try ten more times then give up).

I don't know how to catch all network related exceptions though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connection.execute() (called indirectly by `get()` and `post()`) documents all the exceptions it throws in [its Javadoc](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html#execute%28%29).  They're all subclasses of IOException, so you can catch them all by catching IOException.

To answer the other part of your question, you'd put it in a retry loop like this:

```
int connectionAttempts = 0;
while (map.size() < 5 || connectionAttempts < 10)
    try {
        Document d = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        fillUpMap(d, map);
        //we connected successfully, reset the retry counter
        connectionAttempts = 0;
        if (map.size() < 5)
            /* ... pick a new url for next iteration ... */
    } catch (IOException e) {
        ++connectionAttempts;
    }
```

In practice you might want to retry only in case of timeouts or server errors (500 etc.), stop early on HTTP status codes indicating the request will not succeed (404, 403, 410, etc.), or use a configurable number of attempts.